# Listen for GET callback on pop up window JS

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a payment platform called REDSYS which when the payment  succeeds it redirects to a callback URL (defined by me). To this URL is sent a GET query with the payment result to check it is correct.

Now what I’m doing is redirecting to my web *“https://myhost.com/redsyscallback”*. On load this page is subscribing to a message event, if the message is *“isCallBackResult?”* answers to it with the get query.

The main page which has opened the popup is sending a message *“isCallBackResult?”* to the popup in an interval of 500 ms, and it is subscribed to a message event which will be the get query from the popup answer message.

It works ok, but I know it isn’t the best way. Can any one  help me implementing in any other way?

Main Page code:

```
    const host =
        window.location.protocol +
        '//' +
        window.location.hostname +
        (window.location.port ? ':' + window.location.port : '');

    let newWin = window.open(
        'about:blank',
        'Redirigiendo...',
        'width=800,height=700'
    );

    newWin.addEventListener(
        'load',
        function() {
            //Generated POST form which redirect to the payment page
            var form = newWin.document.createElement('form');
            form.setAttribute('method', 'post');
            form.setAttribute('action', redsysForm.url);

            //API data
            let params = {
                Ds_SignatureVersion: redsysForm.body.Ds_SignatureVersion,
                Ds_MerchantParameters: redsysForm.body.Ds_MerchantParameters,
                Ds_Signature: redsysForm.body.Ds_Signature
            };

            for (var i in params) {
                if (params.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                    var input = newWin.document.createElement('input');
                    input.type = 'hidden';
                    input.name = i;
                    input.value = params[i];
                    form.appendChild(input);
                }
            }
            newWin.document.body.appendChild(form);

            form.submit();

            let interval = setInterval(function() {
                if (newWin.closed) clearInterval(interval);
                console.log('interval');
                newWin.postMessage({ type: 'isCallBackResult?' }, host);
            }, 500);

            window.addEventListener('message', function handler(event) {
                if (event.data.type == 'callBackResult') {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    event.source.close();
                    const result = redsys.processNotification(event.data.data);
                    window.removeEventListener('message', handler);
                }
            });
        },
        false
    );
```

Callback Page Code

```
   const host =
      window.location.protocol +
      '//' +
      window.location.hostname +
      (window.location.port ? ':' + window.location.port : '');

    window.addEventListener('message', event => {
        if (event.data.type == 'isCallBackResult?') {
            event.source.postMessage(
                {
                    type: 'callBackResult',
                    data: this.$route.query //The GET Query by VUE
                },
                host
            );
        }
    });
```